# Mobile images from iPhone not displaying

Tags: php, ios, iphone, image

I have some photos on my iPhone I would like to upload to my website. However, when I try to upload it fails. Some of the errors I received were File name cannot be empty and File is not an image. The thing is when I download a image from the web it works just fine. What am I not understanding here? I am using PHP to upload files to the folder. The example I followed was on [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)  Thanks to all that help.

Comment: Can you add the code to upload the photo, ios side ?

Comment: Share Your Code. We *Can't Assume* Your Problem.

Comment: share your code of both the ends from the PHP side and from the ios side as well